# Expected distance between the center and a uniformly chosen point in a compact and convex region

Tags: geometry, probability-theory, probability-distributions, euclidean-geometry

Consider a compact and convex continuous region $\mathcal{A} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with area $A$, assume the center is $x^*$ and $X$ is a uniformly chosen point, I am wondering if the following conclusion holds.

1. $E[\Vert X-x^* \Vert_2] = c_1 \sqrt{A}$
2. $E[\Vert X-x^* \Vert^2_2] = c_2 A$
   where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants. $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ is the Euclidean norm.

---

I found 1) is generally true according to an approximation of TSP, and 2) is true when $\mathcal{A} $ is a disk or rectangle. But I am wondering **if 2) is true for general compact and convex continuous region $\mathcal{A}$.**

I am also wondering what's the related topic.

Comment: Please clarify what $c_1,c_2$ are allowed to depend on.

Comment: I think given the shape of the area, $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants. For example, if $\mathcal{A}$ is a disk, $c_1 = \frac{2}{3\sqrt{\pi}}$ and $c_2 = \frac{2}{\pi}$.

Comment: Yes, but they do depend on the shape. Then it is not clear what your question is: If you scale a shape by $r$, clearly both the area and the quantity in (2) will change by a factor $r^2$.